# How to show/hide chosen image on button click in query

Tags: html, jquery

I would really appreciete any help in the following task.
The task is pretty simple. I have a couple of paragraphs of text. Each paragraph has a title and desription. Decription should be hidden, and shown only after clicking "plus" button. On click "plus" icon should change to "minus". So far, I have maganed to acheve this. But then, after clicnkin again, text should hide again (that works), but the icon should change to "plus" again. And here I am failing. I have tried many ideas I found in the Internet, but could't make it working.

My HTML code:

```
<div class='toggle-description'>
    <p class='event-type speaker-country'>$event_type</p>
     <button class='plus-button'>
      <img class='plus-icon' src='https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/748/748113.png'>
      <img class='minus-icon' src='https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/43/43625.png'>
     </button>
    <h4 class='lt-opis'>$event_title</h4>
    <div class='more-text' style='display: none;'>
     <p>$event_description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".minus-icon").hide();
  $(".plus-button").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".toggle-description").find(".more-text").toggle();
    var button_plus = $(this).closest(".toggle-description").find(".plus-icon");
    button_plus.css("display", "none");
    var button_minus = $(this).closest(".toggle-description").find(".minus-icon");
    button_minus.css("display", "block");
  });
 });
```

Comment: *"but the icon should change to "plus" again. And here I am failing"* - the problem is that you are hiding the plus/minus button but not actually `toggle` their visibility. you can try to replace that `button_plus.css("display", "none");` with `button_plus.toggle()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the jquery part change this `button_plus.css("display", "none");` to `button_plus.toggle()` and `button_minus.css("display", "block");`  to `button_minus.toggle()` and it works.

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/amritdumre10/vyLe4z9h/3/)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thak you!

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".minus-icon").hide();
  $(".plus-button").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".plus-icon").toggle();
    $(this).find(".minus-icon").toggle();
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='toggle-description'>
    <p class='event-type speaker-country'>$event_type</p>
     <button class='plus-button'>
      <img class='plus-icon' src='https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/748/748113.png'>
      <img class='minus-icon' src='https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/43/43625.png'>
     </button>
    <h4 class='lt-opis'>$event_title</h4>
    <div class='more-text' style='display: none;'>
     <p>$event_description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```